# Masonry doesn't work properly with Meteor

Tags: meteor, jquery-masonry

I have created a test project with Meteor which uses Masonry. I added the package mrt:jquery-masonry(or isotope:isotope), and it works well at the beginning. However, the problem comes now.

Basically, I want to implement the feature that when user clicks the button, the page will be added one more div. Below is my code:

> main.html

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    {{> masonryContent}}
  </div>

  <script>
    (function($){
      var $container = $('.masonry-container');
      $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 300,
        gutterWidth: 50,
        itemSelector: '.masonry-item'
      })
    }(jQuery));
  </script>
</body>
```

> style.css

```
.masonry-item {
  width: 300px;
}
```

> masonry-content.html

```
<template name="masonryContent">
  <div class="masonry-container">
    <div class="masonry-item">
      <p>blabla...</p>
      <p>
        <a href="#" role="button" id="click-me">Button</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="masonry-item">
      <p>test...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="masonry-item">
      <p>another test...</p>
    </div>

    {{#if showItem}}
    <div class="masonry-item">
      <p>new added item...</p>
    </div>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
</template>
```

> masonry-content.js

```
Template.masonryContent.events({
  "click #click-me": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Session.set('show_me', true);
  }
});

Template.masonryContent.helpers({
  showItem: function() {
    return !!Session.get('show_me');
  }
});
```

The problem is when I click the button, the new div was created; however, it wasn't placed by following Masonry rules. The new created item just overlapped to the first item, but I expect it performs the way to append to the last item.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As meteor does partial rendering the element needs to be there in the DOM for masonry to work. So there are two ways of getting over the problem
1) Hide or unhide the element when the button click happens
Or
2) re-render the DOM

You can use the chrome dev tools to see what DOM elements are touched/refreshed (Green color).

[image: Show paint rectangles settings]

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a typo in `masonry` in the template name insertion.
2. Check the package state, many `mrt` packages are not well supported anymore.

Comment: Thanks Julian. the package is mrt:jquery-masonry@0.1.0

Comment: And I tried to use package isotope:isotope, however encounter the same problem.